# Scroll para a próxima section

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Meu código está escrito da seguinte forma:

```
<body>
    <div id="arrow">
        <a class="next"></a>
        <a class="previous"></a>
     </div>

    <section id="primeiro">
    ...
    </section>

    <section id="segundo">
    ...
    </section>

    <section id="terceiro">
    ...
    </section>
</body>
```

O elemento `#arrow` possui `position: fixed`, e ao clicar no `a.next`, queria que ele fosse para a `section` mais próxima, assim também para o `a.previous`, dando um tipo de um `scrollTo`.

**Ex:**
Ao clicar na `a.next` pela primeira vez, ele vai para a `section#primeiro`, na segunda vez, vai para a `section#segundo` e assim vai...

Eu já tentei diversos plugins em JS, porém todos eles bugam o meu código.

Alguém saberia como resolver esse problema?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Depois de um tempinho quebrando a cabeça consegui fazer um script que se aproxima às suas necessidades. Tendo a seguinte página:

```css
#navegacao {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #eaeaea;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

#navegacao a {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navegacao">
    <a href="#prev">Recuar</a>
    <a href="#next">Avançar</a>
</div>

<section id="primeiro" data-navegacao>
    <h2>Primeiro</h2>
Maecenas libero odio, vulputate ut sagittis at, maximus at nibh. Nam leo mi, aliquet ac vestibulum a, porttitor vulputate magna. Maecenas eget elementum nunc. Suspendisse ex urna, commodo et neque eget, pulvinar rutrum mauris. Cras maximus metus cursus, maximus arcu a, iaculis sem. Proin sapien ante, pulvinar ac velit quis, aliquet maximus ante. Nullam lobortis sem diam, et sollicitudin velit sodales sed. Cras tincidunt magna eget ipsum vestibulum, in suscipit purus venenatis. Curabitur malesuada faucibus odio, quis gravida justo porta eu. Integer pellentesque pulvinar lacinia. Cras ut rhoncus tortor. Duis et dapibus magna. Nulla porttitor felis sed risus mollis congue. Mauris commodo, risus quis dignissim volutpat, nisl metus rhoncus metus, quis eleifend orci enim eu nunc. Ut sodales interdum urna, eu molestie lectus rutrum in. Sed condimentum nisi in ex dignissim sodales.
</section>

<section id="segundo" data-navegacao>
    <h2>Segundo</h2>
Maecenas libero odio, vulputate ut sagittis at, maximus at nibh. Nam leo mi, aliquet ac vestibulum a, porttitor vulputate magna. Maecenas eget elementum nunc. Suspendisse ex urna, commodo et neque eget, pulvinar rutrum mauris. Cras maximus metus cursus, maximus arcu a, iaculis sem. Proin sapien ante, pulvinar ac velit quis, aliquet maximus ante. Nullam lobortis sem diam, et sollicitudin velit sodales sed. Cras tincidunt magna eget ipsum vestibulum, in suscipit purus venenatis. Curabitur malesuada faucibus odio, quis gravida justo porta eu. Integer pellentesque pulvinar lacinia. Cras ut rhoncus tortor. Duis et dapibus magna. Nulla porttitor felis sed risus mollis congue. Mauris commodo, risus quis dignissim volutpat, nisl metus rhoncus metus, quis eleifend orci enim eu nunc. Ut sodales interdum urna, eu molestie lectus rutrum in. Sed condimentum nisi in ex dignissim sodales.
</section>

<section id="terceiro" data-navegacao>
    <h2>Terceiro</h2>
Maecenas libero odio, vulputate ut sagittis at, maximus at nibh. Nam leo mi, aliquet ac vestibulum a, porttitor vulputate magna. Maecenas eget elementum nunc. Suspendisse ex urna, commodo et neque eget, pulvinar rutrum mauris. Cras maximus metus cursus, maximus arcu a, iaculis sem. Proin sapien ante, pulvinar ac velit quis, aliquet maximus ante. Nullam lobortis sem diam, et sollicitudin velit sodales sed. Cras tincidunt magna eget ipsum vestibulum, in suscipit purus venenatis. Curabitur malesuada faucibus odio, quis gravida justo porta eu. Integer pellentesque pulvinar lacinia. Cras ut rhoncus tortor. Duis et dapibus magna. Nulla porttitor felis sed risus mollis congue. Mauris commodo, risus quis dignissim volutpat, nisl metus rhoncus metus, quis eleifend orci enim eu nunc. Ut sodales interdum urna, eu molestie lectus rutrum in. Sed condimentum nisi in ex dignissim sodales.
</section>
```

Perceba que nas `sections` eu coloquei a propriedade `data-navegacao`, isso é para selecionar apenas as `sections` que devem ser incluídas no script (para caso você tenha uma que não deve ser utilizada). Explicar em detalhes o script seria maçante, por isso comentei quase todas as linhas para você dar uma estudada nele.

### Script:

```
$(function() {
    // Define o primeiro elemento
    var $last_element = $($('section[data-navegacao]')[0]);

    // Quando a janela rolar...
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Declara a variável para o 'offset' do último elemento
        var last_top = $last_element.offset().top;
        // Declara a variável para o 'offset' da janela
        var w_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        // Percorre todas as 'sections' includias no script
        $('section[data-navegacao]').each(function() {
            // Declara a variável para o 'offset' do elemento atual
            var this_top = $(this).offset().top;
            // Se a janela passou por esse elemento, então este é o "último"
            if (w_top - this_top > 0) {
                // Define o elemento atual sendo o último
                $last_element = $(this);
            }
        });
    });

    // Quando clicar em um dos links do menu...
    $('#navegacao > a').click(function() {
        // Declara a variável para o 'offset' da janela
        var topo = $(window).scrollTop();
        // Se o link for para avançar...
        if ($(this).attr('href') == '#next') {
            // Percorre todas as 'sections' includias no script
            $('section[data-navegacao]').each(function() {
                // Declara a variável para o 'offset' do elemento atual
                var elemento_topo = $(this).offset().top;
                // Se a subtração de 'elemento_topo' com 'topo' for maior que 0, significa que o elemento atual é o próximo
                if (parseInt(elemento_topo - topo) > 0) {
                    // Move o usuário para o elemento
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: elemento_topo
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                };
            });
            // Se o link não é para avançar, verifica se é para voltar
        } else if ($(this).attr('href') == '#prev') {
            // Move o usuário de volta para o último elemento
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $last_element.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        };
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85ra9g3c/